# Scheme/Racket equivalent of ualarm

Tags: timer, scheme, posix, racket

Is there a Racket/Scheme equivalent of [ualarm](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm)?

i.e. how can one set a system timer in Racket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want some action to occur asynchronously after `time-to-wait` milliseconds, you can use [`alarm-evt`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sync.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._alarm-evt%29%29), like this:

```
(thread
 (lambda ()
   (sync (alarm-evt (+ (current-inexact-milliseconds) time-to-wait)))
   .... do something here ....))
```

Depending on what you're doing, Óscar's answer (`timer%`) may be more convenient, though.

Answer (score 4):

Not *exactly* like `ualarm` (this is not a system call!), but perhaps you can use [`timer%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/timer_.html) to do what you intend:

> A `timer%` object encapsulates an event-based alarm. To use a timer, either instantiate it with a `timer-callback` thunk to perform the alarm-based action, or derive a new class and override the `notify` method to perform the alarm-based action. Start a timer with `start` and stop it with `stop`. Supplying an initial `interval` (in milliseconds) when creating a timer also starts the timer.